# How to merge contiguous intervals in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find an efficient way to merge/combine contiguous intervals defined by a category. For example, from this source table:

```
TYPE   START    END    CATEGORY
----   -----    ----   --------
X         0        5      A
X         5       10      B
X        10       15      B
X        15       20      C
X        20       25      C
Y         0        6      A
Y         6       12      A
Y        12       20      B
Y        20       22      B
Y        24       27      B
Y        27       30      B
Y        35       40      C
```

Query output should be:

```
TYPE   START    END    CATEGORY
----   -----    ----   --------
X         0        5      A
X         5       15      B
X        15       25      C
Y         0       12      A
Y        12       22      B
Y        24       30      B
Y        35       40      C
```

Note that for type Y there's a gap between 22 and 24, so a new combined interval is required.

Using SQL Server 2008R2. Data volume is in the thousands of records, so not too huge.

It feels like this is a job for recursive CTEs, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as a "gaps and islands" problem. Here's my stab at it:

```
with cte as (
    select * from (values
        ('X',         0,        5,      'A'),
        ('X',         5,       10,      'B'),
        ('X',        10,       15,      'B'),
        ('X',        15,       20,      'C'),
        ('X',        20,       25,      'C'),
        ('Y',         0,        6,      'A'),
        ('Y',         6,       12,      'A'),
        ('Y',        12,       20,      'B'),
        ('Y',        20,       22,      'B'),
        ('Y',        24,       27,      'B'),
        ('Y',        27,       30,      'B'),
        ('Y',        35,       40,      'C')
    ) as x( [Type], [Start], [End], [Category] )
), with_grp as (
    select *, n.Number - dense_rank() over (partition by [Type], [Category] order by n.Number ) as grp
    from cte
    join dbadmin.dbo.Numbers as n
        on n.Number >= cte.Start
        and n.Number <= cte.[End]
)
select [Type], [Category], min([Start]), max([End])
from with_grp
group by [Type], [Category], [grp]
order by [Type], [Category], min([Start])
```

Where dbadmin.dbo.Numbers is a tally table (a table with a single column and the rows being the numbers 1-(some large-ish number)). To uncover the magic, do a raw select from the `with_grp` cte. But that should do it.

Comment: Thanks, this is getting me most of the way there! However, my actual [Start] and [End] numbers are arbitrary and include decimals (e.g. could have an interval from 2.45 to 38.9). I've tried to use a tally table based on the distinct Start and End values rather than an existing whole numbers table. This mostly works except that the nice 'magic' difference between a rank and a number breaks down. It seems null values for Category are ignored as a gap. E.g. for (B,B,null,B,B), it created two records: one for the null interval and another all the way from the start to end of the Bs.

Comment: So, yes I did have to make a tally table based on the actual [Start]/[End] values, but added another column to it that had the row_number(). This way I could compare [Start]s and [End]s against their true values, but do the grouping by the RowNum-dense_rank(). Thanks again!!

Comment: Based on your first comment, I'd have multiplied everything by 100 to make it an integer, do the method above, and then divide by 100 (or alternatively just carry some extra columns through the cte) at the end. Either way though, it sounds like you got something working. :)